# How to connect to AWS RabbitMQ from C#?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, rabbitmq

In my C# application, I have this code:

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory
        {
            Port = 5671,
            UserName = "userxxxx",
            Password = "passwordxxx",
            HostName = "amqps://xxxx.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
        };
        using var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
```

But during the CreateConnection I receive:

```
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException
   HResult=0x80131620
   Message=None of the specified endpoints were reachable
   Source=RabbitMQ.Client
```

The AWS Console shows me:

> Endpoint: amqps://xxxx.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:5671

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your C# application running?  On-premises?  Same VPC as rabbitmq?  Different VPC?

Comment: My c# app is running on my local PC

Comment: @ZedZip did you got your solution i am also struggling with same issue

Answer (score 2):

Use a tool like "netcat" to verify you can connect to port 5671 on the AWS MQ.  Netcat should be used from **the same host** you are trying to connect from.  Alternatively, consider using a cloud-based portscanner like https://www.whatismyip.com/port-scanner/ to take your local network out of the equation.

Successful example with netcat:

> $ nc -vz myownawsmq.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 5671
> Connection to  myownawsmq.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com 5671 port [tcp/amqps] succeeded!

If you get an error or timeout, then your URL is incorrect or port 5671 is blocked.

When I created my AWS RabbitMQ instance, port 5671 was open to the internet because publicly accessible is the default. You cannot use a security group with RabbitMQ instance that is publicly accessible. If you set Private Access for the RabbitMQ instance, you won't be able to reach it externally.

It's also possible 5671 is blocked by local firewall rules. Check the firewall configuration in your local network to make sure 5671 is allowed.  If a cloud-based port scanner can connect to the port, but a local scan can't, it's probably your local network configuration.

Comment: You wrote " You cannot use a security group with RabbitMQ instance that is publicly accessible", i.e. I think it should be " You cannot use a security group with RabbitMQ instance that is NOT publicly accessible"?

Comment: I have scanned the url using Zenmap from my local machine and received:  Failed to resolve "prefix.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:5671". Probably something is wrong in AWS RabbitMQ settings but what ?

Comment: As of March 2021, AWS did not support security groups for public RabbitMQ brokers.  See https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=336502.  Seems counterintuitive since a public RabbitMQ is where you would really want a security group.

Comment: Zenmap scan failed most likely because you have the port in the hostname. Try ""prefix.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com".  Once scan is done, check port list and make sure 5671 is there.

Comment: I have scanned the url without port using ZenMap: the host was found and traceroute built from my local machine to AWS. But: it found only one opened port: 443. What  can I do else?

Comment: Make sure your broker has Public Access (you may need to recreate to give it public acces), and verify your local firewall rules are not blocking 5671.  Consider a cloud-based  port scanner like https://www.whatismyip.com/port-scanner/ to take your local network out of the equation.

Comment: Thank you! I have used your link, the result is: 
Port 5671: Status : closed , incoming traffic denied, i.e. it means I need to add inbound  rule to my local  machine ?